# UITableView reloadData looping

Tags: swift, uitableview, cllocationmanager

In my app, I'm updating a `UITableView` based on the user's location. I'm doing this inside the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. Now, what happens is that my `UITableView` will keep reloading and thus not drawing anything. When I comment out the `reloadData()` call, all is fine (without the location ofcourse). When I add it back in, the `print()` is executed once. After that the table keeps reloading.

```
extension RestaurantsViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if (locations.count > 0) {
            if (location?.coordinate.longitude != locations[0].coordinate.longitude && location?.coordinate.latitude != locations[0].coordinate.latitude) {
                location = locations[0]
                print("will reload table")
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Off the top of my head: make sure `self.tableView.reloadData()` is being executed on the main thread

Comment: Good idea, I did add it, but it changed nothing. 

Comment: Make sure you don't have any `reloadData()` in your table view delegate or data source functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stopUpdating your location after once found it. Add this `manager.stopUpdatingLocation()` after reloading `tableView`

```
extension RestaurantsViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if (locations.count > 0) {
            if (location?.coordinate.longitude != locations[0].coordinate.longitude && location?.coordinate.latitude != locations[0].coordinate.latitude) {
                location = locations[0]
                print("will reload table")
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's also not the issue. I'm only reloading if the location differs, but also: adding your code didn't fix the issue.

Comment: can you post some more code please? Maybe you are calling somewhere else reloadData()